# I don't understand how ng-if work in a list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-if

I don't understand how ng-if works:

I would like that a button in a list is visible only
if a condition is verified. 
In the example below, a button should only be visible 
if a list element has title == 'Title2'

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="o in options">{{o.title}}
        <button ng-if="o.title=='Title2'">BTN</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But as you can see from the 
[code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VedFfa?p=preview) all array elements show up

Comment: Note: replacing `ng-if` with `ng-show` works in your plnkr. I'm still investigating why this is.

Comment: You're using an ante-diluvian version of angular (in Internet time), which is full of bugs fixed since. Here's an up-do-date version, which works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/5m9Rk9zcheklKzsjd6SK?p=preview

Comment: For me your plunker worked as it is. Anyway I will sugest you use `===` for comparison just as good practices and because of type coercion